# Parse string for a yes/no response

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to parse a user response from a SMS message. Specifically I am looking for a Yes/No response. As i've encountered different replies i've adjusted the searching routine.

I'm sure this is not a unique problem, what has anyone used used to determine user intent from a yes/no response?

```
    Dim SearchString = Regex.Replace(Message, "[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "")
    Dim ResultString = SearchString.Split({" "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    Dim indexNo = From i In Enumerable.Range(0, ResultString.Length)
          Where String.Equals(ResultString(i), "no", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Or String.Equals(ResultString(i), "n", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
          Select i

    Dim indexYes = From i In Enumerable.Range(0, ResultString.Length)
         Where String.Equals(ResultString(i), "yes", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Or String.Equals(ResultString(i), "y", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
         Select i
```

I originally used IndexOf() but if the message contained some other note containing a Y or N it could be parsed incorrectly.

Comment: What are the possible responses from the users? Maybe the instruction to respond with "yes" or "no" is not clear enough. You can use IndexOf with a string as well as a character.

Comment: People tend to not listen is what I've found. Its a SMS message so they can send anything they please. The initial message says Reply YES to confirm or NO to cancel. If i cant determine their intent, i send another SMS saying "I didn't understand your response. Please reply with only YES or NO"

Comment: If there is no context to that instruction, you might get replies like "who this?" You might want to ask over on [User Experience Stack Exchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) about ways to get the users to be more obedient, errr... I mean supply a response which you can parse.